# Does averaging/filtering an autocorrelation input signal wrongfully change the output?

Tags: signal-processing, sensors, correlation, moving-average

I'm investigating sensor measurements of NO2 in the atmosphere over the course of several days. My first interest is to find periodicity of the data to which end I'm using autocorrelation.

My problem is that the praxis seems to be to use moving average as well as filtering of the measurements; moving average of about 10-50 data points and readings set **above** the sensors maximum reading of 200µg/m³ is set to 200µg/m³ (as far as my understanding goes on that).

Anyhow... When performing my autocorrelation I found that processing the raw signal or the averaged/filtered signal gives wildly different results, as can be seen in appended autocorrelation figure (bottom), which leads me to my question:

**When performing autocorrelation, do I wrongfully change the result by using an averaged/filtered input signal to my autocorrelation function? And if so, which way is "correct"?**

[On top: RAW sensor measurement of NO2 concentration, NO moving average/filtering! Middle: measurement processed with a moving average of 30 data points and any reading >200 is set to 200. Bottom: autocorrelation of the two above measurements, with some slight smoothing. Right scale is inactive and possible end effects are not interesting.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/scw3M.png)

Comments on the figure: I know it looks bad/weird that the moving average signal is flat most of the time, and that this flatness is not at a constant 200 (max). This is really not of interest, the behavior of autocorrelation is my concern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Applying a moving average before autocorrelating is the same as applying the moving average twice (once forward and once backward) after autocorrelating.

Let `*` denote convolution and `^R` denote time-reversal of a signal.  `x` and `m` are your input signal and moving average filter

```
AutoCorrelate(x*m) = (x*m) * (x*m)^R  
                   = x * m * x^R * m^R
                   = x * x^R * m * m^R
                   = AutoCorrelate(x) * (m * m^R)
```

Note that a moving average filter is the same shape as it's time-reversal, so by filtering the signal before autocorrelation, you have filtered the autocorrelation twice.

Since a moving average filter is a low-pass this explains why the curves in your autocorrelation are smoothed out.

Whether or not this is appropriate really depends on your application.  If the moving average filter only removes noise, then it's a good idea.  If the moving average removes important parts of the signal that indicate its timing, then it's not a good idea.

Comment: Nice! This is, really, exactly what I wanted. I understand from what you are saying that the filtering process I'm doing, where I use a max/min value of my input signal is probably a horrible idea.
Do you have a good source for where you learned this? Want to learn more out of interest! Or is it all "by heart" hehe...?